# Perl - How do I escape/encode special characters

Tags: perl

I'm writing a script for IRC and sometimes I might need to use a color. Normally I do it this way

```
my $C = chr(3);
```

`$C` is the control code used for color but I've seen some other script that escapes it something like "\x\v...". How do I get the correct encoded version of that? I tried `Data::Dumper` but I didn't find it. I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: @Wireless There are certain conventions on this site. One is that, if you ask a question, and you get good and correct answers, you check one as "accepted" which earns the person who put time and effort into answering your question 15 rep points. It does not matter if you found the answer elsewhere: **The question you posted here was indeed answered**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to specify `chr(3)` with a hexadecimal escape code is to use:

```
print "\x03\n";
```

or, in octal:

```
print "\003\n";
```

or, as a control code:

```
print "\cC\n";
```

See [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> The following escape sequences are available in constructs that interpolate and in transliterations.
>
> 1. `\t` tab (HT, TAB)
> 2. `\n` newline (NL)
> 3. `\r` return (CR)
> 4. `\f` form feed (FF)
> 5. `\b` backspace (BS)
> 6. `\a` alarm (bell) (BEL)
> 7. `\e` escape (ESC)
> 8. **`\033` octal char (example: ESC)**
> 9. **`\x1b` hex char (example: ESC)**
> 10. `\x{263a}` wide hex char (example: SMILEY)
> 11. **`\c[` control char (example: ESC)**
> 12. `\N{name}` named Unicode character

Comment: perlop! I checked perlsyn, perldata, and perlintro looking for this.

Comment: @mobrule: I cheated: http://www.google.com/search?q=character+escape+sequence+site%3Aperldoc.perl.org

Answer (score 5):

Characters with codes on the range 0 .. 255 can be expressed in a number of ways. These example all print the character `A`:

```
print chr(65);
print "\101";     # octal notation
print "\x41";     # hexidecimal notation (and hexadecimal notation)
printf "%c",65;
```

---

or for your particular problem:

```
print chr(3);
print "\003";
print "\3";
print "\x03";     # hexidecimal notation (and hexadecimal notation)
printf "%c",3;
print "\cc";      # from Sinan's answer
print "\cC";
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So I think it's the hexadecimal notation that I've seen in the other scripts. So how would I go about converting chr(3) to a hexadecimal notation?

Comment: @mobrule I think you have covered all the bases ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can print hex-encoded (or even octal- or binary-encoded) characters through a number of mechanisms (and this is not a comprehensive list by any means):

```
# generate strings from hex:
my $space_char = sprintf("%x", 0x20);
my $space_char2 = "\x20";
my $space_char3 = 0x20;
my $space_char4 = pack("L", 0x20);
my $space_char5 = chr(0x20);
```

You can read about these functions at [perldoc perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#Alphabetical-Listing-of-Perl-Functions) or individually via [perldoc -f sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html), [perldoc -f pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html), [perldoc -f chr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html) etc.

For more about hexadecimal, octal and binary numbers in general, see "Scalar value constructors" under [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors).

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to get the hex version of chr(3) not the other way round?

Comment: I found the answer. Thanks everyone

Comment: @Wireless What the heck does "I found the answer" mean? There are some very good answers here such as the ones given by @Ether and @mobrule. **You should check one of them as the answer to the question you asked here.**

Comment: Sorry, that was just a follow up to the previous comment about the example "chr(3)".

Answer (score 1):

See the sections **Escape sequences** and **Character Classes and other Special Escapes** in [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).